# Android menu does not show German umlaut Ü

Tags: character-encoding, icons, diacritics, android-menu

I just added a German localization to my app, and I am realy wondering, why the menu doesn't display some German umlauts.

menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

...     
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_about"
        android:title="@string/app_menu_about"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
    />

</menu>
```

strings.xml:

```
<string name="app_menu_about">äöüÄÖÜß</string>
```

only the lowercase umlauts and the ß are shown correctly. The uppercase umlauts are show as AOU. So they are displayed as normal chars.
If I remove the menu item icon, the umlauts are shown correctly. Why can't i have upper case umlauts and an icon?

Is there anything you know I can do to be able to show the uppercase umlauts correctly, and also use an icon?

I wan't to localize more languages, but if I can not display all special chars correctly it's not worth the work.

Answer (score 2):

What I have found so far (if anyone comes across this post): http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3974

Use the workaround presented by chris@orr.me.uk at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess, but it may be displaying them but for some reason the top few pixels are being cut off when the icon is displayed.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too. But the German language is not the only one using non default characters. So how could Google create default images for menus, which do not take care about these special chars.